# Hadoop: Error while copy file local directory to Hdfs

Tags: hadoop

When i try to copy directory of 3 files in hdfs i get following errors

```
     hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg
12/08/01 23:48:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
12/08/01 23:48:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
12/08/01 23:48:46 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg20417.txt" - Aborting...
copyFromLocal: java.io.IOException: File /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/hduser/gutenberg/gutenberg/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
```

My fsck output is

```
hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop fsck -blocks
FSCK started by hduser from /127.0.0.1 for path / at Wed Aug 01 23:50:49 IST 2012
Status: HEALTHY
Total size: 0 B
Total dirs: 10
Total files:    0 (Files currently being written: 2)
Total blocks (validated):   0
Minimally replicated blocks:    0
Over-replicated blocks: 0
Under-replicated blocks:    0
Mis-replicated blocks:      0
Default replication factor: 1
Average block replication:  0.0
Corrupt blocks:     0
Missing replicas:       0
Number of data-nodes:       0
Number of racks:        0
FSCK ended at Wed Aug 01 23:50:49 IST 2012 in 3 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY
```

Also when i try to format namenode i get following error

```
hduser@saket-K53SM:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop namenode -format
12/08/01 23:53:07 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = saket-K53SM/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.3
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-   1.0 -r 1335192; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Tue May  8 20:31:25 UTC 2012

Re-format filesystem in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name ? (Y or N) y
Format aborted in /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name
12/08/01 23:53:09 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at saket-K53SM/127.0.1.1
```

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Can you look in the logs for your NameNode and paste any relevant error / warn messages

Comment: also can you do jps and check if all the processes are working properly?

Answer (score 6):

I believe its a very silly issue. Enter “Y” instead of lower case "y" (its supposed to be uppercase)

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. I did the same (I entered `y` instead of `Y`) and it didn't reformat the filesystem.

Comment: It's true, it only formats on uppercase 'Y'. moronkreacionz is clearly not a moron!

Comment: Thanks for the sweet comment, JesperSM.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to:

- stop namenode
- stop datanode
- delete /app/hadoop*
- format namenode
- start datanode and namenode again

Answer (score 0):

After stopping all the daemons (i.g stop-all.sh),delete **data** directory which holds the temporary files of namenode . After deleting **data** directory start again the hadoop daemons i.g start-all.sh.
 The path of the "data" directory is the value of **hadoop.tmp.dir** property in **conf/core-site.xml .**

I think this will fix your problem